# Every non-eventually constant sequence in $\beta N$ is discrete?

Tags: general-topology

Let $(x_n)_n$ a non-eventual constant sequence in $\beta N$. It's well know that $(x_n)$ is not convergent. In particular, the same property can be applied to any of its subsequences. So, is it true that the set 
$$\{x_n: n\in N\}$$
is discrete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not necessarily.  For instance, if you take any non-eventually constant sequence $(y_n)$, then since $\beta\mathbb{N}$ is compact, it must accumulate at some point $y\in\beta\mathbb{N}$.  Now define a sequence $\{x_n\}$ by $x_0=y$ and $x_n=y_{n-1}$ for $n>0$.  Then $\{x_n\}$ is not discrete, since the point $x_0=y$ is not isolated.

Answer (score 2):

Let $x_0\in \beta\mathbb N\setminus \mathbb N$, and let $x_n=n$ for $n\in\mathbb N$. Clearly $(x_n)_{n\in\omega}$ is not eventually constant. And $\{x_n:n\in\omega\}$ is not discrete, as $x_0\in \overline{\mathbb N}=\overline{\{x_n:n\in\mathbb N\}}$.